# Changing Datatype from int to bigint for tables containing billions of rows

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have couple tables with millions, and in some table billions, of rows, with one column as int now I am changing to bigint. I tried changing datatype using SSMS and it failed after a couple of hours as transaction log full.

Another approach I took is to create a new column and started updating value from old column to new column in batches, by setting `ROWCOUNT` property to 100000, it works but it very slow and it claims full server memory. With this approach, it may take a couple of days to complete, and it won't be acceptable in production.

What is the fast\best way to change datatype? The source column is not identity column and duplicate, and null is allowed. The table has an index on other columns, shall disabling index will speed up the process? Will adding Begin Tran and Commit help?

Comment: Do you need this as a production capability, to be executed on a regular basis? Or is this a one-time thing?

Comment: This needs to be done only one time

Answer (score 7):

I ran a test for the ALTER COLUMN that shows the actual time required to make the change. The results show that the ALTER COLUMN is *not* instantaneous, and the time required grows linearly.

```
RecordCt    Elapsed Mcs
----------- -----------
      10000      184019
     100000     1814181
    1000000    18410841
```

My recommendation would be to batch it as you suggested. Create a new column, and pre-populate the column over time using a combination of **ROWCOUNT** and **WAITFOR**.

Code your script so that the WAITFOR value is read from a table. That way you can modify the WAITFOR value on-the-fly as your production server starts to bog down. You can shorten the WAITFOR during off-peak hours. (You can even use DMVs to make your WAITFOR value automatic, but this is certainly more complex.)

This is a complex update that will require planning and a lot of babysitting.

Rob

---

Here is the ALTER COLUMN test code.

```
USE tempdb;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTable'))
    DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (
    ColID   int              IDENTITY,
    ColTest int              NULL,
    ColGuid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000

UPDATE dbo.TestTable SET ColTest = ColID;
GO

DECLARE @t1 time(7) = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @t2 time(7);

ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable ALTER COLUMN ColTest bigint NULL;

SET @t2 = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT
    MAX(ColID)              AS RecordCt,
    DATEDIFF(mcs, @t1, @t2) AS [Elapsed Mcs]
FROM dbo.TestTable;
```

Comment: +1 for a pretty complete example. I'd be curious about what would happen if there was a clustered index on the table, and prior to changing the columns the index was rebuilt with `FILLFACTOR=80` (rows will grow from 24 bytes to 28, an increase of ~15%). It should save SQL Server allocating new pages. Repeat for other indexes that use the new `BIGINT` column as a key or covering column.

Comment: Results for 10k rows as is: 430,725 mcs; with clustered index: 155,295 mcs; with clustered index rebuilt at `FILLFACTOR=80`: 98,647 mcs

Answer (score 0):

a simple `alter table <table> alter column <column> bigint null` should take basically no time. there won't be any conversion issues or null checks - i don't see why this wouldn't be relatively instant

if you do it through the GUI, it'll probably try to create a temp table, drop the existing table, and create a new one - definitely don't do that

Comment: The rows will grow in size. So if a page is full of rows a new page must be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016+, this `alter table <table> alter column <column> bigint null` statement will be a simple metadata change (instant) if the table is fully compressed.

More info here from @Paul White:

https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/database-design/new-metadata-column-changes-sql-server-2016

```
Compression must be enabled:
    On all indexes and partitions, including the base heap or clustered index.
    Either ROW or PAGE compression.
    Indexes and partitions may use a mixture of these compression levels. The important thing is there are no uncompressed indexes or partitions.
    Changing from NULL to NOT NULL is not allowed.
The following integer type changes are supported:
    smallint to integer or bigint.
    integer to bigint.
    smallmoney to money (uses integer representation internally).
The following string and binary type changes are supported:
    char(n) to char(m) or varchar(m)
    nchar(n) to nchar(m) or nvarchar(m)
    binary(n) to binary(m) or varbinary(m)
    All of the above only for n < m and m != max
    Collation changes are not allowed
```